# Keep 60 lines in log file

Tags: linux, file, backup, lines

I've got log file, which I would like to have 60 lines in.
When there will appear 61 line, script should cut line from beginning and paste it at end of my backup log file.

But I have not any idea how to do that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of:

1. `tail --lines=60 my_log` to get the last 60 lines of your log file
2. `head --lines=-60 my_log` to get all but the last 60 lines of your log file

I'm sure you can figure the rest out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite the file without the first line, as there is no way of truncating a file from the beginning.

In other words, you need to read the file line by line, and write every line except the first to a new file. Append the first line to your backup log file, and then rename the new file as the old file.

You will need to ensure that the old file is not written to in between your finishing reading it and overwriting it. You may want to use file locking to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

See @MartinBroadhurst's answer above.

If you don't need to print the log until the end of your program, you could keep all of the lines in a buffer for processing until the program completes and your done, i.e.

```
vector<string> logBuf, backupLogBuf;
...
while( ... ) {
    /* do whatever you're doing, storing lines to 'logBuf' instead of the logfile */
    if(logBuf.size() >= 61) { 
         backupLogBuf.push_back(logBuf.front());
         logBuf.erase(logBuf.begin());
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use 2 separate files? You can show the last 60 lines of the backup-file with

```
tail log_file -n 60
```

Or updates on the fly

```
tail -f log_file -n 60
```

with

```
tail -f log_file -n 60 > short_log_file
```

you can generate the 60 lines file

Comment: Cause I want to show it on website :) And don't want to download x MB file, just to show part of it. Thanks